# WP Custom Fields Metabox Disappears - ACF plugin issue

Tags: custom-field, metabox, advanced-custom-fields, screen-options

The WP custom fields metabox on all posts (including CPTs) disappear, and the checkbox in a post's Screen Options is also gone. This only happens when Advanced Custom Fields is activated. None of my ACF field groups hide the custom fields metabox, nor does deactivating all of my field groups solve the problem. How do I get the custom fields metabox to display on my posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACF 5.6+ intentionally removes the custom fields metabox to improve performance when loading posts. To display the metabox, add this to `functions.php` in your theme:

```
add_filter( 'acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false' );
```

In addition to the above code, make sure that the custom fields metabox is enabled in Screen Options at the top of a post, and that an individual ACF field group is not disabling the custom fields functionality in its settings.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/known-issues/#acf-5.6.0